# Store Virus/Keylogger on hardware component?

Tags: virus, hardware, physical

Is it possible to store a virus or key logger or something of that kind on a hardware that transmits data? 
I have recently bought a USB from Aliexpres and there is a bump on the cable, I did some research and apparently it's ferrite bead, but what if It isn't? Is it possible to create something that will do execute operation when plugged in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt that a little bump on the cable would be enough room to hide a listening or attacking device.

But it is possible to hide such a device in an usb cable. One well-known example is the Cottonmouth-1 used by the NSA.